# Convert a string to a date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

how do I convert this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate varchar = 'Feb 2020'
```

to a Date like this

```
DD/MM/YYYY or DDMMYYYY
```

I need to sort some dates and from the combobox you can just choose those three : Dez 2019, Jan 2020 or Feb 2020.
So I thought I could do something like that:

```
DECLARE @FromDate varchar = 'Feb 2020';


SELECT RIGHT(convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar, PIN_DATE)), 106),8)
FROM PIN
WHERE RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar, PIN_DATE)), 106),8) 
= CONVERT(datetime, @FromDate,106)
```

The date in PIN_DATE looks like this : YYYYMMDD aka. 20201231

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: 'Feb 2020' is not a date - so that is a bigger problem. Define what logic you wish to use for the day portion during conversion first BEFORE you start coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ERROR:

```
DECLARE @FromDate varchar = 'Feb 2020'
```

This assigns `@FromDate` as a SINGLE character, so the value is `'F'`.

When using the character types in SQL Server, *always* use a length:

```
DECLARE @FromDate varchar(255) = 'Feb 2020'
```